# Format to show day of week in month using C# or MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, date-format

I'm trying to format a date in a MonoTouch project to display a string like:

```
 1st Saturday of the month, February 2, 2013
```

but I have been unable to find a way to format it in C#.

I have previously been able to do this in Objective C by using a formatter like:

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"F'st' EEEE 'of the month', MMMM d, yyyy"];
```

and replacing '2st' with '2nd', '3st' with '3rd', etc but I have been unable to find a replacement for the 'F' character.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: please don't answer your question within the question - add an answer instead. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the previous answers were close, but both had an error in the same place.  Here is the code I am using to get the occurrence of a day of the week in the month:

```
int dowin = (SelectedDate.Day - 1) / 7 + 1;
switch(dowin){
    case 1:{
        return "1st" + dateString;
    }
    case 2:{
        return "2nd" + dateString;
    }
    case 3:{
        return "3rd" + dateString;
    }
    case 4:{
        return "4th" + dateString;
    }
    case 5:{
        return "5th" + dateString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like `DateTime.Now.Day / 7 + 1` will give you that number, then you add the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard format specifier to do this, but it should be fairly simple to calculate:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

int day = date.Day;

int ordinal = (day / 7) + 1;

// if it's the first occurrence, ordinal will be 1, 2nd will be 2, etc
```

(I haven't run that through the compiler to check, but I think the basic idea works)